# Error message when running aspnetcore app in Docker Container on Heroku

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, heroku

I'm looking to run an ASP.Net Core application in a Docker container on Heroku, and I think I'm almost there but I am getting the error message below after deploying via Github Actions.

The Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/alexjcampbell/Airborn/blob/main/Airborn.Web/Dockerfile) and the Github action is [here](https://github.com/alexjcampbell/Airborn/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml).

The reason I am using Github Actions to build the Docker image is that I am working on an M1 Macbook and Docker on that can't build an x86 image that Heroku can run :(

Any suggestions would be most most appreciated!

```
2021-04-17T03:43:20.218963+00:00 app[web.1]:       The application 'Airborn.Web.dll' does not exist.
2021-04-17T03:43:20.218963+00:00 app[web.1]:   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2021-04-17T03:43:20.218964+00:00 app[web.1]:       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
2021-04-17T03:43:20.218964+00:00 app[web.1]:       Install a .NET SDK from:
2021-04-17T03:43:20.218965+00:00 app[web.1]:         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
2021-04-17T03:43:20.304166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 145
2021-04-17T03:43:20.387844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-17T03:43:22.573740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=airbornco.herokuapp.com request_id=6a8216e5-73d8-4b30-85ab-ad7669d0b019 fwd="47.72.46.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-04-17T03:43:23.329992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=airbornco.herokuapp.com request_id=e7ca81e5-9cdc-4098-9b01-64308a3ac4a6 fwd="47.72.46.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-04-17T03:43:23.729319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=airbornco.herokuapp.com request_id=c7cf8e71-d618-4812-bd91-93b4f7c2d352 fwd="47.72.46.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```